# Help understanding inequalities in a proof

Tags: real-analysis

I need some help understanding a step in a proof.  Instead of writing the exact details of the proof, I will try to formulate the concept that I am having trouble with. If what I've written does not make sense, please let me know.

Assume that $|f'(t)|\leq|\alpha|$ holds for some real function $f$ and $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$.

Also assume that for some real function $g$ and $y,y'\in\mathbb{R}$, we have that $g(y)-g(y')=f(1)-f(0)=\int_{0}^{1}f'(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$.

Then it follows that: 
$$|g(y)-g(y')|\leq\int_{0}^{1}|f'(t)|\,\mathrm{d}t\leq|\alpha|.$$

*Would someone care to explain how this follows from what is known?*

Comment: The first inequality is the "triangle inequality" for integrals. Namely that, $ | \int f | \leq \int |f|$. The second inequality can be looked at in two ways: If $|f| \leq M$ on a set A, then $\int_A |f| \leq \mu (A)M$. In this case, the set $A$ is $[0, 1]$ which has (Lebesgue) measure $1$. The second way to look at it follows from the implication: $f \leq g \implies \int f \leq \int g$. In this scenario, $|\alpha|$ is playing the role of $g$. Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Yes, it helped. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use the fact that 
$$\left|\int_0^1g(t)dt\right|\leq\int_0^1|g(t)|dt $$
Which follows from $-|g(t)|\leq g(t) \leq |g(t)|$. We have
$$|g(y)-g(y')|=\left|\int_0^1f'(t)dt\right| \leq \int_0^1|f'(t)|dt \leq \int_0^1|\alpha|dt =|\alpha|$$